# Modify this Python to send only one color image

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have this python script to work with Telebot to watermark images in Telegram and then send back the watermarked image in the bot chat.
I have obtained this from Github and wish to change it but I'm failing somehow.

**Current flow**

1. Send image to watermark bot
2. Watermark bot will download the image, add the watermark in both Black and White
3. Watermark bot will send back two images in the chat, one of each color

**Desired flow**

1. Just one color (White) be sent back.

**CODE 1**

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw, ImageEnhance
import hashlib
import piexif
import config


def getting_ready(path):
    fname = md5(path) + '.jpg'
    image = Image.open(path).convert('RGB')
    try:
        exif_dict = piexif.load(image.info['exif'])
        orientation = exif_dict['0th'][274]
    except KeyError:
        orientation = None
    rotate_values = {3: 180, 6: 270, 8: 90}
    if orientation in rotate_values:
        image = image.rotate(rotate_values[orientation], expand=True)
    for color in ['black', 'white']:
        watermark(image, fname, color)
    return fname


def watermark(img, new_fname, color):
    text = config.WATERMARK
    wm = Image.new('RGBA', img.size, (0, 0, 0, 0))
    fontsize = img.size[1] // 100 * config.FONT_SIZE
    font = ImageFont.truetype(f'tools/fonts/{config.FONT_NAME}', fontsize)
    indent = fontsize // 6
    w, h = font.getsize(text)
    text_position = (img.size[0] - w - indent, img.size[1] - h - indent)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(wm, 'RGBA')
    draw.text(text_position, text, font=font, fill=color)
    alpha = wm.split()[3]
    alpha = ImageEnhance.Brightness(alpha).enhance(config.TRANSPARENCY)
    wm.putalpha(alpha)
    out_path = 'images/out/{}/{}'.format(color, new_fname)
    Image.composite(wm, img, wm).save(out_path, 'JPEG', optimize=False, quality=config.QUALITY)


def md5(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        md5hash = hashlib.md5()
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b''):
            md5hash.update(chunk)
    return md5hash.hexdigest()
```

**CODE TWO**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import telebot
import config
import random
import os
import time
from tools.tools import getting_ready

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.BOT_TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hi, Send or Forward me a PHOTO!')


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_all(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Send /start or /help')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
def send_watermark(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    sent_message = bot.reply_to(message, 'Downloading...')
    message_id = sent_message.message_id
    file = bot.get_file(message.photo[0].file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file.file_path)
    bot.edit_message_text(f'Downloaded!\n\nNow, Genarating Watermarks...\n\ncurrent watermark: {config.WATERMARK}', chat_id=chat_id, message_id=message_id)
    __path = 'images/' + str(random.randint(100000, 999999)) + '.tmp'
    with open(__path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(downloaded_file)
    fname = getting_ready(__path)
    os.remove(__path)
    time.sleep(2)
    bot.edit_message_text('Now, Uploading...', chat_id=chat_id, message_id=message_id)
    for i in ('black', 'white'):
        __file = 'images/out/{}/{}'.format(i, fname)
        __photo = open(__file, 'rb')
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, __photo, reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)
        os.remove(__file)
    bot.delete_message(chat_id=chat_id, message_id=message_id)


print('watermark bot started successfully!')
bot.polling()
```

**Steps I've tried**

1. Modified `['black', 'white']` to `['white']` results in an error
2. Modified `for i in ('black', 'white'):` to `for i in ('white')` and results in an error.

I can't figure out what else, tried changing some things I just don't understand like `Image.composite(wm, img, wm).save` to remove an instance of wm.

Comment: As a side note, `for i in ('white'):` will result in i being 'w', 'h', 'i', 't', and 'e'.  You would want `for i in ('white',):`.

Comment: Thank you this worked for me. Another quick question, what do I change in order to modify the position of the watermark and the scale of the image (original image it's adding the watermark to)
There is a "Config" key called "QUALITY" which I've set to 100 but it still reduces the overal image size, making it smaller

Comment: Surely you can see that the `watermark` function calls `draw.text` and passes `text_position`,  If you want to change the size, use `img.resize` at the top of `watermark`.